# Bootstrap slider for rails simple form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

As a Rails newbie and wannabe enthusiast, I am trying to have sliders in a form partial and struggling!

I have downloaded the bootstrap-slider-rails gem and the simple-form-for gem.

In a new file which I called slider.js in my assets file, it only inlcudes:

```
$("#slider").slider();
```

In the form partial which uses simple_form_for I have put the following as as entry:

```
= f.text_field :parameter_1, id: 'slider', type: 'text', data: {'slider-id' => 'slider', 'slider-min' => '0', 'slider-max' => '40', 'slider-step' => '1', 'slider-value' => '14' }
```

I have added the following to application.css.scss

```
 *= require bootstrap-slider
```

And the following to application.js, at the bottom:

```
//= require bootstrap-slider
```

All I get out is a normal text box? Help please!

Comment: Did you figure this out? I can't find an example of how to use the slider